# How to set the DNS name to Azure vm using terraform

Tags: azure-devops, terraform

I am able to deploy the VM on azure using terraform but I found that after provisioning the DNS name not set?
I am not sure how to make DNS there on azure portal while provisioning the vm using [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1HkK.png) Terraform

What exactly I need is the hostname generated while deploying VM over azure get in this format . server name along with  france.central.azure.com
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/862fY.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a static IP address to your VM. You may add an A record to point to your instance using the below sample.

```html
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "us-east-1"
}

resource "azurerm_dns_zone" "example" {
  name                = "yourdomain.com"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_dns_a_record" "example" {
  name                = "your a record name"
  zone_name           = azurerm_dns_zone.example.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  ttl                 = 300
  records             = ["<Insert your Instance-ip>"]
}
```

Comment: It got fixed by using resource "azurerm_public_ip" "myterraformpublicip" {
  name                = "myPublicIP"
  location            = "francecentral"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  domain_name_label   = "constellation"

  tags = {
    environment = "Terraform Demo"
  }
}